# JQuery & HTML: How to use echo $_POST to get data from one form to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im creating an application using JQuery and HTML. In the first form i you are asked to enter a id, then once this is checked you are asked to add in more information. The problem that i am having is that after you press submit in the second page i want to save all the information together, this includes the id entered in the first page.

I forms are created using HTML and the functionality is done using JQuery. I am trying to use the following code but it is not working

```
var id = echo $_POST['cardNumber'];
```

I am using this in one of the .js pages. Here is the HTML from the first page that is asking for the ID

```
<form id="RegisterForm" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="registerCardForm" action="register.html"> 
        <input type="text" id="cardNumberRegField" type="tel"  name="cardNumber" class="required number register" minlength="16" maxlength="16"/> 
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to store php value in a js variable you should do this, without quotation marks js variable is set `undefined`:

```
var id = "<?php echo $_POST['cardNumber']; ?>"
```

Comment: when i try this, it is just setting the id  to "<?php echo $_POST['cardNumber']; ?>" and it is not getting the actually number that you enter

Comment: when you use php `post` global variable the value should come from the page that is posted to page, do you use 2 forms in one page?

Comment: no, i have only one form on each page... i have index.html which is the first screen and register.html which is the second screen.... i also am not using any PHP if that makes a difference to this?

Comment: that's because you use html extension to save the register page, it should be register.php and run it on the server like wamp or mamp.

Comment: is there any way of doing this that you know that will let me keep the html extensions?

Comment: yes, you can read this article: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm